# How to Seek Audio/Video Data with Variable Bitrate (VBR)?

Tags: algorithm, video, audio, media

This might be a way too generic question, but what is the general approach for seeking within media files (video or audio of any kind/format) if the data has variable bitrate (VBR)?

It seems an easy thing to do if the stream has a constant bitrate (CBR). E.g. if you know it is 256 kbit/s and you want to seek forward/backward by 30 seconds, just calculate how many bits that are (approximately), convert that to byte and seek that many byte forwards/backwards in the file. Finally keep on reading and parsing till the next header/block-start/keyframe/whatever is found and continue playback from there.

Okay, but what do you do if the bitrate is highly variable? E.g. it can be anything from 32 to 512 kbit/s and keeps changing frequently? I know that this might depend on audio/video format. Some file formats have index tables at the beginning/end you might use and some files contain pointers in the stream how many bytes to skip for skipping the next X seconds. In that case you can work with that information, however, what if the format has no such table or pointers?

The most naive approach I can think of is to just estimate the bitrate as good as possible (e.g. by looking at the average bitrate of the last couple of seconds you played back), jumping where you think it could be correct according to the estimated bitrate, and look how far you really jumped. If you jumped too much, try jumping back a bit. If you jumped too little, try jumping forward a bit. Maybe keep jumping in one direction till you jumped too far again, now reverse the direction again as well as the step size (similar to a binary search algorithm). Each time you jumped too far, you reverse the direction and decrease the step size. You will get closer and closer to the correct point and if you are close enough (below some chosen delta), just start playing again (after all the jump doesn't have to be accurate to the millisecond).

While the algorithm above might work, it sounds rather poor and is probably very slow in practice. So how is it really done? Anyone ever wrote a media player/player-plugin of some kind? Or is it just like this that every "decent" format supporting VBR must have some kind of index tables or skip pointers in the stream if it expects software to correctly seek and not just play from start to end?

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you do "jump" and afterwards you are able to look where you jumped, then you're already using a player, don't you? I use BASS library that allows me to "jump" and to check current playtime. As far as I know, all players and libraries that have the notion of jumping allow you to specify the time. So, what's the problem? I am missing something there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why (for example) DVDs use VOB files instead of raw bitstreams. With a VOB file you get not only the bitstream itself, but also pointers to consecutive frames, so you can skip to another frame quickly and easily.

OTOH, most video bit streams *are* designed so it's fairly easy to synchronize and find the beginning of a frame (necessary for things like broadcast TV), so estimating (and rounding down), then searching for a frame start works reasonably well also. Many also have constraints on the maximum compression rate that's acceptable, so careful estimation can give you reasonably close to the beginning of a frame.

Comment: Well, synchronizing is one thing, finding the right position within the file a different one. The problem with VBR is that when I jump into the middle of the file, I might be close to the middle of the media, or close to the beginning or close to the end, depending on how much the bitrate varies. The fact that I can synchronize quickly will only quickly tell me, that I jumped to the wrong position. And always working my way from the beginning of the file, even if I can skip frames quickly, is still not that fast (especially when data is read from CD or network).

Comment: @Mecki:It's certainly a lot faster to jump directly to the point you want. Ease of synchronization is useful primarily because it lets you quickly figure out where you are, so even though you may be in the wrong place, it's at least quick and easy to find out you're in the wrong place, and make another attempt at finding the right place.

Comment: Since this is the best answer so far and I have little hope than anyone can come up with a better answer, I decided to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The binary search algorithm that you describe is more or less how [seeking in Ogg Vorbis files work](http://wiki.xiph.org/GranulePosAndSeeking). I've never seen another format use it, most use some kind of index structure for seeking.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping to see, but definitely valuable information, because I didn't know that's the case. +1 for sharing this information with us.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a coarse index to your file at the beginning, with the location of a fixed number of seek points within the file.  At each such seek point, you can store a sub-index of seek points within that section of the file, and so on recursively.  You can look at this as a kind of B+ tree, but with nodes stored immediately before the data they index.

I don't know if anyone actually does that, but it should be much faster than the binary search you described, especially if each seek is mechanical and therefore slow.

Comment: This sounds like an idea. Instead of long delays on each seek this will cause a short delay in the beginning (creating an index), but later seeks will be much faster because of that index. Works well with files on HD, where you have truly random access - works worse on slow seeking media like CD/DVD and even worse when accessing data over a (possibly very slow) network of course.